# aligned text in ul tag

Tags: css

I'm showing the text using ul and li tag.

```
<ul class="archive-item-list-pt">
    <li><a href="/blogs/2012/9/22/reading-and-writing.html">Reading and writing</a></li>  
    <li><a href="/blogs/2012/9/22/celebrations-arent-what-they-used-to-be.html">Celebrations aren’t what they used to be</a></li>
</ul>
```

in case when text is long it is showing the text below the (disc).I want to aligned first and second line.

Comment: Did you try `list-style-position: outside;` ?

Comment: yes it is removing the (list-style-type:square).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the [`list-style-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/list-style-position) to `outside`:

```css
.archive-item-list-pt {
    list-style-position: outside;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qMM5x/

---

Or use the shorthand property:

```css
.archive-item-list-pt {
    list-style: square outside;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nfYVP/

Comment: when I use it it is not showing the list-style-type:square.I want to show list style type square also

Comment: @RohitSharma, Thats because, he is not defining it to show as square, just add `list-style: square` on the declaration.

Comment: @RohitSharma - Try using the shorthand property.